# Factorization of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Let $I$ be the following ideal of $R$:
$$I:=(3,1+\sqrt{5})$$
My teacher said that the following equation holds:
$$I^2=(3)I,$$
but I actually can't understand why... I can write
$$I^2=(9,3+3\sqrt{5},6+2\sqrt{5})$$
but how the third generator of $I^2$ can be expressed as an element of the ideal generated by $3$ in $R$ times the ideal $I$?

Since the factorization $I^2=(3)I$ seems to be false, how can I find two essentially different factorizations (i.e. giving two different prime decompositions) of $I^2$?

Comment: The third generator is definitely not in $3I$. By definition, $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{5}$ is not even in the base ring $R$ because $\frac{2}{3}$ is not an integer.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy thank you very much, maybe you know a factorization of $I^2$ different from $I\cdot I$? I want to factorize $I^2$ in two essentially different ways, but the one in the question, as you remark, is wrong!

Comment: Since you have accepted the answer by Martin Brandenburg to the question _in the comment_, maybe you would want to change the _question itself_ so that it corresponds to what you really wanted to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to factorize $I^2$ in two essentially different ways

Calculate $I^2=(\sqrt{5},3)$. The automorphism $\sqrt{5} \mapsto -\sqrt{5}$ of the ring gives that $(-\sqrt{5},3)=J^2$ where $J=(3,1-\sqrt{5})$. Hence $I^2=J^2$.

EDIT: Actually $(3,1+\sqrt{5})=(1)$ (see Jyrki's answer). In particular we cannot produce a non-unique factorization from this. Instead, take $I:=(2,1+\sqrt{5})$. Observe that $I$ is a maximal ideal, since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]/I = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-5,2,1+x)=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(1+x)=\mathbb{F}_2$. One can calculate $I^2=(4,2+2 \sqrt{5})=(2) \cdot I$. But $(2)$ is not a prime ideal; perhaps a product of prime ideals?

Comment: I understand and accept your answer, thank you...but can i ask you if $I^2=I$?

Answer (score 6):

Something is wrong here?
$$1+\sqrt5\in I \implies (1-\sqrt5)(1+\sqrt5)=-4\in I.$$
$$-4\in I, 3\in I\implies 1\in I\implies I=R.$$

Comment: No I don't think so. Curiously, the results of my answer are correct, but for trivial reasons. Also observe that $(\sqrt{5},3)=(1)$. Probably one has to start with $I=(2,1+\sqrt{5})$ to get something interesting.

Comment: A good idea, @Martin. But $(2,1+\sqrt5)=(2,1-\sqrt5)$, so your trick may not work?